# Violation count is not matching at module level

Tags: sonarqube

```
On Violations drilldown, the cumulation count of all the violations as per severity doesn't match the count at the module level violations count.
```

[Please find the below link for the snapshot of the violation mismatch](http://share.pho.to/9Yzx0)

The sonar analysis is run on sonar-3.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Sonar 3.3.1 is no longer supported, the current Long-Term-Support version being SonarQube 4.5.4.

I highly advice you to upgrade your installation instead of attempting to troubleshoot an unsupported product.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, i have already tried building the project in upgraded version of sonarqube(4.5.4) and i am still facing the same issue of violations not matching at module level . Please find the link for screenshot:http://share.pho.to/9ZNdO